# Is $\log(1+x)\sim x$ correct?

Tags: calculus, analysis

This is my problem if $\log(1+x)\sim x$ when we are given $x\to 0$?

The assignment doesn't mention if $\log$ is $\log_{10}$ or $\log_{e}$? I assumed the first version and saw the claim is wrong. Am I on a right track?

Comment: How do you saw the claim is wrong?

Comment: yes, you can surely assume that it's base $e$

Comment: What does ~ mean? $\log$ and $\ln$ are synonyms almost everywhere.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: I assumed $\log$ as to be $\log_{10}$ and so it would be $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{\ln 10}$.

Comment: @PVAL I don't know if that's true (scientific applications)

Comment: @PVAL: $f \sim g$ means $f/g \to 1$.

Comment: I think you are right to be cautious about assuming a natural logarithm, although this is necessary to get the strongest conclusion, $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} = 1$.  A doubt about whether $\log_{10}$ or $\log_e$ was intended is best resolved by your instructor (whom I would hope appreciates your caution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely go with the taylor expansion around the origin:

$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\mathcal O(n^4)\simeq x \ \ for \ |x|\ll 1$$

Comment: So, you consider the `log` to be as @Jyrki took?

Comment: Definitely! First off because the behavious of all logarithms $\log_b,\ b>1$ (as for example $log_{10}$ and $\ln$) is asymptotically identical in the critical regions (hence $\rightarrow 0, \ and\ \rightarrow \infty$). And secondly because the "hidden" meaning (the convention) of $\log$ is based on the context it is used: for example base 10 is usually used to plot graphs, whereas base 2 is used in the runtime of algorithms, and again base $e$ is the one used in analysis.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \log_b(1+x) = \lim_{x \to 0}\log_b(1) = 0$$

Because $b^0 = 1 \space \forall b$